# In the LinkedList Java Core Collection, what is the use of addLast?

Tags: java, collections

I have a Linked List object called `ll`. I added some data into that object. Assume that are like following:

```
LinkedList ll = new LinkedList();

ll.add("Mohan");

ll.add("Rajesh");

ll.addFirst("Kumar");

ll.addLast("Nammu");

ll.add("Divyesh");
```

My question is: if I already  inserted 100 data,  when I use `addFirst()` method then that data will be insert at First, but the same functionality should happen for `addLast()` method also, which means if anywhere i use `addLast()` method also it has to insert data at last, but if I add any more data after `addLast()` method that data only inserting at last then what is the use of `addLast()` method instead of that we can use just add() method only right ?

Comment: `addLast` complements `addFirst` in the interface which has these two.  The older Collection interface just has `add` which added to the end.

Answer (score 21):

[`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) class implements both [`Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) and [`Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) interface. It inherits [`add(E)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#add%28E%29) method from `Queue`, and [`addLast(E)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#addLast%28E%29) method from `Deque`. Both the methods have same functionality.

Answer (score 3):

As the javadoc states, `addLast` and `add` are equivalent: [addLast(E e)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#addLast%28E%29)

Answer (score 1):

> javap java.util.LinkedList
>
> Compiled from "LinkedList.java"
>
> public class java.util.LinkedList extends java.util.AbstractSequentialList implements java.util.List, java.util.Deque, java.lang.Cloneable, java.io.Serializable {

you can see here that LinkedList extends AbstractSequentialList and it implements list interface, add and remove are the methods from this interface you can check it with the following command

> javap java.util.List

Compiled from "List.java"

public interface java.util.List extends java.util.Collection {

public abstract int size();

public abstract boolean isEmpty();

public abstract boolean contains(java.lang.Object);

public abstract java.util.Iterator iterator();

public abstract java.lang.Object[] toArray();

public abstract  T[] toArray(T[]);

public abstract boolean add(E);

public abstract boolean remove(java.lang.Object);

public abstract boolean containsAll(java.util.Collection);

public abstract boolean addAll(java.util.Collection);

public abstract boolean addAll(int, java.util.Collection);

public abstract boolean removeAll(java.util.Collection);

public abstract boolean retainAll(java.util.Collection);

public void replaceAll(java.util.function.UnaryOperator);

public void sort(java.util.Comparator);

public abstract void clear();

public abstract boolean equals(java.lang.Object);

public abstract int hashCode();

public abstract E get(int);

public abstract E set(int, E);

public abstract void add(int, E);

public abstract E remove(int);

public abstract int indexOf(java.lang.Object);

public abstract int lastIndexOf(java.lang.Object);

public abstract java.util.ListIterator listIterator();

public abstract java.util.ListIterator listIterator(int);

public abstract java.util.List subList(int, int);

public java.util.Spliterator spliterator();

}

actually the method add and addLast does the same thing but because of the above reason It have both methods.

I think I have given the answer. feel free to comment...

Answer (score 0):

Method : boolean add(E e) and adddLast(E) are equivalent.

Shown here [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#add%28E%29)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, checking the code of the LinkedList class, there is a small difference:

**[`add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html#add(E)) method return type is boolean and it is hardcoded to true in the return statement, and [`addLast()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html#addLast(E)) return type is void.**

Besides that, they do the same.